# Using viewport width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1 doesnt fit my page to my phone screen

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have this but when I open the webpage on my phone it is wider than the screen.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

so I have to pinch in to make it fit.
Might this be caused by the fact that there are some images used as the background of the html page? For instance, further below I have the following:

```
<img src="index_files/img2.png" width="970">
```

I don't know much about HTML so I will not be able to understand complex answers.

I also saw some `div` elements with absolute dimensions like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sm-12">
            <div class="blue-bg">
                <h3 style="color: #F37620; font-weight: bold; font-size: 22px; background: #34495D; width: 400px; text-align: center; padding: 10px;margin-bottom: 0;  margin-left: 56.6%; text-transform: uppercase;" "=""> requirements specification </h3>

                <img src="index_files/img2.png" width="970">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="sm-6">
                        <h6 style="font-weight: bold;
```

As you can see it has a `width: 400px` and there's a lot of this going on in this html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Couple things:**

Your meta viewport tag is simply setting the scale at which the viewport is set to. It has nothing to do with your images.

Your image is not a background image in the technical sense.  A background image is a css property of an element.

You have a fixed width on your img of 970px.  That is why it's wider than your viewport.

A quick fix is:

**Change:**

```
<img src="index_files/img2.png" width="970">
```

**to:**

```
<img src="index_files/img2.png" style="width: 100%"/>
```

This will set your img width to 100% of it's containing element. So as long as that containing element is fluid, you're good to go.

Unless you want that image to be 970px and have the ability to scroll it to see the hidden portions on small screens, then you need to start playing with `overflow` css properties.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've edited my question to add some more information about divs with absolute sizes, can you check it out and tell me if I should do something about them as well? The html file comes from an adobe illustrator infographic, exported as html.

Comment: I would remove the inline style for width or try setting it to auto.  Any time you use fixed widths on elements, it's going to certainly create issues with your responsiveness.  By nature, there is nothing responsive about something that is fixed. :)

Comment: So if I just remove the styling for those images everything will stay the same and the viewport tag will start working?

Comment: In theory yes. But perhaps no.  If you're exporting code from Adobe Illustrator, who knows what you're going to get.  So I wouldn't really be able to say "yes that will work" without looking at the whole codebase including any CSS. But the principle is this... if you want your application to be fluid and responsive to screen size, never use fixed widths (unless you are properly using media queries and breakpoints).  Use percentages.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the meta tag doesn't make it fit, but simply tells the browser to display the page at a scale of 1 (or 100% of it's original size) rather than trying to shrink it down to fit. To make the page fit you will need to ensure the content is smaller than the width of the device, or that the styles allow for it to respond to the width of the device. I'd suggest looking up some resources on responsive design as this is a pretty large area to try and cover here.